# Ошибка при использовании Telebot с requests

Tags: python, telegram, requests, бот, telebot

Делаю бота который запрашивает информацию с игрового сервера и выводит ее пользователю. Но при написании любого никнейма (Например: NeModerator, айди которого 3395940) выдает ошибку:

```
2019-09-11 19:41:03,759 (util.py:65 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: 

"ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\\\'t parse entities: Can\\\'t find end of the entity starting at byte offset 203"}\']',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "VimeInfo.py", line 361, in playerInfo
    parse_mode="Markdown")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 598, in send_message
    reply_markup, parse_mode, disable_notification))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 140, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
    return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
    raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\'t parse entities: Can\'t find end of the entity starting at byte offset 203"}']
"
2019-09-11 19:41:03,767 (__init__.py:417 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\'t parse entities: Can\'t find end of the entity starting at byte offset 203"}']"
```

Часть кода:

```
    if message.text == "О игроке":
    def playerInfo(message):
        nickname = message.text
        searchId = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/user/name/" +str(nickname))
        forCheck = [x.get("username") for x in searchId.json()]
        idPlayer = [x.get("id") for x in searchId.json()]

        statsGet = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/user/" +str(idPlayer[0])+ "/stats")
        username = statsGet.json()["user"].get("username")
        level = statsGet.json()["user"].get("level")
        rank = statsGet.json()["user"].get("rank")

        guild = statsGet.json()["user"].get("guild").get("name")
        guildLevel = statsGet.json()["user"].get("guild").get("level")
        guildTag = statsGet.json()["user"].get("guild").get("tag")
        guildAva = statsGet.json()["user"].get("guild").get("avatar_url")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                            " ️ О игроке *" +str(username)+ "*: \n    Привилегия: *" +str(rank)+ "* \n    Уровень: *" +str(level)+ "* \n    Гильдия: *" +str(guild)+ "* \n       Уровень: *" +str(guildLevel)+ "* \n       Тег: *" +str(guildTag)+ "() [ ]() \n \n ️ Статистика на режимах: ",
                            parse_mode="Markdown")


    searchIf = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                    " ⚠️ Какой ник у игрока?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(searchIf, playerInfo)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему

Comment: Вы не закрыли последний символ `*`. Telegram использует Markdown. Так как `*` не закрыта, произошла ошибка парсинга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не закрыли последний символ `*`.

`Telegram` использует `Markdown`, поэтому если `*` будет непарной, произойдёт ошибка парсинга.
Просто добавьте ещё одну `*` в сообщение:

***Пример:***

```py
bot.send_message(
    message.chat.id,
    " ️ О игроке *" +str(username)+ "*: \n    Привилегия: *" +str(rank)+ "* \n    Уровень: *" +str(level)+ "* \n    Гильдия: *" +str(guild)+ "* \n       Уровень: *" +str(guildLevel)+ "* \n       Тег: *" +str(guildTag)+ "*() [ ]() \n \n ️ Статистика на режимах: ",
    parse_mode="Markdown"
)
```